# Illustrator: What is the difference between rotating a symbol with the Selection Tool vs the Free Transform Tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I ask this because I just discovered and filed a bug that apparently outlines all the strokes of a symbol when expanded, given it has been rotated or scaled with the Free Transform Tool. Replicable in Illustrator CC 2015.0 and 2015.3.

Is there reason Illustrator should be outlining the strokes of an expanded symbol rotated via Free Transform but not for those rotated with the Selection Tool? Is there any way to determine with which tool a symbol was rotated? Seems there is some fundamental difference, although possibly not visible to the user.

Comment: No idea why, but I can repro on CS6 too.

Comment: Is there some skew or perspective deformation involved?

Comment: @joojaa I can reproduce with nothing other than a rotation

Comment: @Cai yes, ok.  There might be a very small residue in the matrix that causes this but that is a bug then.

Comment: @Cai CS6 huh? Must be an long standing bug. I should just make a habit of not using Free Transform tool unless I'm skewing or distorting...

Comment: follow-up: this bug still exists in CC 2017. the best workaround is to ensure the symbol whose link is being broken contains a shape that is "open" (i.e. is not made of a stroke forming a full, closed loop)

Answer (score 1):

I double checked with many different scenarios. Unfortunately there is no way to determine that which object is rotated with which tool.

You are right to file the bug :)